# How do I get Google Docs approval workflow informations using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am new in Google Apps Script (and in Stack Overflow so i'm sorry if i'm doing something wrong). I'm trying to get approval workflow informations of a document and print it on the document.
I would need to extract from the document using Apps Script the following informations:
-if the document has been locked for approval
-who is the last user who approved the document and when it was approved
-a list of all the users who have to approve

I've looked in the Google documentation and on the internet but I only manged to find a way to get the last user who modified the document and when it was last modified as shown below.

```
var lastUpdated = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getLastUpdated();
const obj = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {supportsTeamDrives: true});
user = obj.lastModifyingUserName
```

These information are not linked to the workflow and don't tell me if the approval workflow has started or not.
Is there a way to get the informations that I need?
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please be more specific about ```approval workflow informations```, what do you consider as approved?

Comment: Sure, in Google Docs under the file tab there is the option "Approvals". Clicking on that opens a window where you can insert a list of people (using their email) to whom you want to send the document and you can also lock the document so that they can't edit it. These people will then receive the doocument and they have the possibility to click on "Approve" or "Reject". I managed to get the information about the document being locked or not but I would need to get also the list of people that has been inserted on the "Approvals" window and whether they clicked on "Approve" or "Reject".

Comment: Thank you for the details and sorry for the delay. The functions you are looking for doesn't exist yet, but this feature has been requested. Add a star to improve chance of development : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208025958